# How can I create an event to control the animation from python code?

Tags: python, animation

I'm working on online object that will appear on the internet. My problem is I don't know how to create a key that will helps me to manipulate the character animation when it's appear on the service. I really need your help ASAP

- as you can see this is my animation but I don't know how to continue.
  [image]

Comment: 'On the internet 'is a bit vague. In GE you can specify that the animation starts, only when the object is activated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.